# dynamic css properties with jquery (on scroll)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

I have a hero section which has a background image. I wish to create a parallax effect by editing the `background-position` property on scroll. I have a JavaScript file which is below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        // Parallax effect
        parallax.effect(); // TODO: rename this function
    });
});

// Global variables
var currentWindowPos = $(window).scrollTop();

var parallax = {
    // Variables
    element: $('.hero.hero-bg'),
    bgPosition: 0,

    // Functions
    effect: function () {
        $(parallax.element).css({
            'background-position': '0 -' + parseInt(360 + (currentWindowPos * .025)) + 'px'
        });
    }
};
```

I have removed other dynamic effects such as adding classes to the navigation bar once the page has been scrolled over a certain point. I can see in Chrome that the element is getting the dynamic `background-position` property but the image doesn't seem to be doing anything.

In Chrome, if I manually go into Developer Tools and add the `background-position` property and use my arrow keys to increase or decrease the value in the text field, I can see the image move up and down/left or right.

Also in Chrome, if I attempt to *untick* the CSS property in the `element.style` section, it does not get a strike through, just like other properties once they have been disabled. Please see below.

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

Could someone explain why this issue is occurring and could someone provide the solution?

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d8t2cnqp/) for the person in the comments.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please share your jsfiddle or code to know the problem in detail ?

Comment: Edited. Please see updated question.

Comment: ok now what you want ?? 
you want background image for the whole div ??

Comment: you can do background-position :center !important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a variable with value that's not changing at all.

```
var currentWindowPos = $(window).scrollTop();
```

Variable `currentWindowPos` has the initial `scrollTop` value, that is zero. You never update it. As I am able to notice, you are trying to apply a parallax effect to your image. Try changing this line

```
'background-position': '0 -' + parseInt(360 + (currentWindowPos * .025)) + 'px'
```

to something like this

```
'background-position': 'center -' + $(window).scrollTop() * 0.5 + 'px'
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        // Parallax effect
        parallax.effect(); // TODO: rename this function
    });
});

var parallax = {
    // Variables
    element: $('.hero.hero-bg'),
    bgPosition: 0,

    // Functions
    effect: function() {
        $(parallax.element).css({
            'background-position': 'center -' + $(window).scrollTop()*0.5+'px'
        });
    }
};
```

```css
.hero {
    width: 100%;
    height: 34rem;
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(23, 162, 184, 0.7), rgba(10, 97, 135, 0.7));
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.hero.hero-bg {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.hero.hero-bg:after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 34rem;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(23, 162, 184, 0.7), rgba(10, 97, 135, 0.7));
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.hero .inner-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hero hero-bg" style="background-image: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/eNB8HLrxcD4/maxresdefault.jpg');">
    <h1>Hero section</h1>
</div>

<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
```

Of course, you can edit the `*0.5` to adjust the speed.

Comment: That's great - thanks very much! It's always the small issues.. Thanks again.